# Monitoring blocked requests in varnish

Tags: command-line, query, varnish

I set up a blacklist in varnish where a bunch of IPs that I suspect for malicious intentions are blocked.

I'm trying now to see if there's a way to monitor if any of these IPs made any request and if varnish blocked them or not. Ideally in real time.

I turned to [VSL queries](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/reference/vsl-query.html#vsl-query-7) and using a command like `varnishlog -q "RespStatus eq 403"` I managed to get a bunch of information about blocked requests.

I just can't figure out how to do this in real-time and track only IP and URL instead of all other information I don't need.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Simply substitute your use of `varnishlog` with `varnishncsa`. AFAIK, they accept the same arguments, but the output of the latter is much more concise, resembling that of Apache or NGINX access log formats.